# Hibernate One To Many Mapping 2 Levels

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hbmxml

I have 3 Tables - Lease Account, Lease, Transaction. 
Each Lease Account has N Leases, each Lease has N Transactions.
I am allowed to do only 1 query to the database - Select * from Lease Account, to fetch all this data into Java as N Lease Account objects - each Lease Account object containing a  of Lease objects - each Lease containing a  of Transaction objects.

Can somebody please guide me on how to write the one to many mapping (hbm.xml) for this scenario in Hibernate(3.2) ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

In your lease account hbm xml

```
<class name="LeaseAccounts" table="lease">

    <id name="leaseAccountsId" type="java.lang.Long" column="id" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

<set name="lease" table="lease_accounts"
                    inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
                <key>
                    <column name="id" not-null="true" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="Lease.class" />
            </set>


</class>
```

Similarly you can write for your lease table.
NB: Select * will load all data or not depends upon your lazy initialization. If [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate) is set to true , then your need to do [Hibernate.initialize(your collection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666928/what-does-hibernate-initialize-do)

(The lazy attribute tells hibernate when to get the children.
The fetch attribute tells hibernate how to get the children.)